# R dplyr - Create multiple new columns from a string containing separated values

Tags: r

I am very new to R, and it's very different to mainstream languages, so bear with me. Given a tibble:

```
# A tibble: 58 x 5
   device_id         ts notes                                                   date job                                                         
   <chr>          <int> <chr>                                                  <int> <chr>                                                       
 1 2C7970    1623194811 NA                                                1570487178 Advice-Action1-Action3                                          
 2 2C7A55    1623195767 NA                                                1567554149 Advice-Action1                                          
 3 2C7A55    1623195785 NA                                                1582152167 Action1-Action2-Action3
 4 2C7A55    1623195785 NA                                                1582152167 NA
```

Is there a way to

1. Create a factor for all the values in the job string. We know they are separated by a '-' character.
2. Create a new column for each factor.
3. Put a Y or N for each row to indicate if that value is present for that row.

So you'd end up with something like

```
# A tibble: 58 x 5
       device_id         ts  notes            date  advice  action1  action2  action3                                                         
       <chr>           <int> <chr>           <int>   <lgl>    <lgl>    <lgl>    <lgl>                                                       
     1 2C7970    1623194811    NA       1570487178    TRUE     TRUE   FALSE      TRUE 
     2 2C7A55    1623194811    NA       1570487178    TRUE     TRUE   FALSE     FALSE      
     3 2C7A55    1623194811    NA       1570487178    FALSE    TRUE   TRUE       TRUE
     3 2C7A55    1623194811    NA       1570487178    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE     FALSE
```

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` library you can use  `separate_rows` to split the `job` column on `'-'`, create a `TRUE` column and get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(job, sep = '-') %>%
  mutate(value = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(job) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = job, values_from = value, values_fill = FALSE) %>%
  select(-`NA`, -row)

# device_id         ts       date Action1 Action2 Action3 Advice
#  <chr>          <int>      <int> <lgl>   <lgl>   <lgl>   <lgl> 
#1 2C7970    1623194811 1570487178 TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    TRUE  
#2 2C7A55    1623195767 1567554149 TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   TRUE  
#3 2C7A55    1623195785 1582152167 TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE 
#4 2C7A55    1623195785 1582152167 FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
```